# Downloading files from web memory

Tags: javascript, file, download, arraybuffer

I have indexedDB in browser with objects like `{name: 'img.jpg', data: 'ArrayBuffer(12342)'}`. I need to create possibility to dowload an object in to my computer as file named like `name` argument in the object using javascript.

Comment: It is not a problem to get an object from database only download it as file

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should do the work, it has to be modified accordingly.

```
let indexedObj = {name: 'img.jpg', data: 'ArrayBuffer(12342)'}; // suppose this is your indexedDB object
const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
const a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.download = indexedObj.name;
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(indexedObj.data);
a.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
a.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now but only for text files. If I download object storing image, It is not posible to open it.

Comment: it might not be formatted/stored properly, you have to log out the array buffer or see if any errors appears in the console